# Expectation of absolute value of stationary time series

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expectation, time-series

Let $Y_t$ be a stochastic process (time series).
We consider stationarity as follows:

$Y_t$ is said to stationary if the mean $\mu_t = \mathbb{E}(Y_t)$ is constant (given $\mathbb{E}|Y_t|<\infty$) and the autocovariance function $\text{Cov}(Y_t, Y_{t+k})$ depends only on the lag $k$.

I am wondering if this stationarity property of a given process $Y_t$ has an implication on the expectation of its absolute value : $\mathbb{E}|Y_t|$.

Is this also constant ? Can we quantify the difference $\mathbb{E}|Y_t| - \mathbb{E}(Y_t)$ ?
To be precise I want to find an upper bound for the sum :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \beta^{2i} \mathbb{E}\left(|Y_{t-i}| -  \ Y_{t-i} \right),$$
for a given $\beta$ such that $|\beta|<1$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you said in the problem statement is the definition of weakly stationary process, not second order stationary process.

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously $E|Y_{t-i}|\leqslant\sqrt{E(Y_{t-i}^2)}=\sqrt{\sigma^2+\mu^2}$, where $\sigma^2=\mathrm{Cov}(Y_t,Y_t)$ and $\mu=E[Y_t)$ do not depend on $t$, hence
$$
\sum_{i\geqslant0}\beta^{2i}E(|Y_{t-i}|-Y_{t-i})\leqslant\sum_{i\geqslant0}\beta^{2i}\left(\sqrt{\sigma^2+\mu^2}-\mu\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\sigma^2+\mu^2}-\mu}{1-\beta^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. However the fact that $\mathbb{E}(|Y_t|)$ is bounded for all $t$ by the same upper bound does not imply that $\mathbb{E}(|Y_t|)$ is constant over $t$, right ?

Comment: That's correct, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

More over, as far as I know second order stationary process is different from weakly stationary process. May be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) helps.

Comment: I removed "weakly stationary" in my question as it seems ambiguous. The definition is just that the first moment is constant and autocovaraince depends only on the lag. So the fact that $\mathbb{E}|Y_t| = \frac{\theta}{2}$ in your example does not show that |$Y_t|$ is not stationary (its first moment does not depend on $t$).

Comment: My answer was not correct, but weakly stationary is not ambiguous and it is what you defined in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a paper where 'second-order' and 'weakly' stationarity are the same. The naming is not really important here. I removed it in my question and let only the definition.

Comment: If you have Papoulis's stochastic process book available, on page 394 on memoryless systems, it says if $x(t)$(input) is WSS(as you wrote) then $y(t)$(output) might not be stationary in any sense. I am not sure about absolute value, but I don't think it necessarily would be WSS. I will continue working on it. **But** it says if the input is stationary of order $N$ the output will be stationary of order $N$

Comment: I made an important edit to my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $f$ be a continuous function then if $Y_t$ and $Y_s$ are identically distributed, $f(Y_t)$ and $f(Y_s)$ will also be identically distributed.

Proof. Let $z_t=f(Y_t)$ and $z_s=f(Y_s)$. Define $\Omega=\{x:f(x)<\omega\}$. Then $\Pr\{z_t\leq \omega\}=\Pr\{Y_t\in \Omega\}$. The latter is nothing but $\Pr\{Y_s\in \Omega\}$ which is $\Pr\{z_s\leq \omega\}$.

Applying this simply result to the continuous function of absolute value, it can easily be seen than $|Y_t|$ is also stationary and hence $E|Y_t|$ is constant over time.